# Why dunk three times in a mikva?

Tags: minhag, mikvah-ritual-bath, niddah

Some Ashkenaz women dunk once in a mikva, some twice, and some three times.  What is the basis or rationale for dunking three times?

Comment: There is a Noda B'Yehuda on this

Comment: IIRC At least for men, one should do at least three dunks, and if he does more, it should be an odd number (presumably because of zugos being dangerous).

Comment: Zugos by mitzvos?

Answer (score 6):

The Sefer Chasidim ([siman 294](https://www.sefaria.org/Sefer_Hasidim.394.1?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he)) brings a source for this practice. Namely, that "*tahor*" is found three times in a *passuk* in Tanach that relates to the mitzvah of immersion.

The *p'sukim* are:

**1)** [Ezekiel 36:5](https://www.sefaria.org/Ezekiel.36.25?lang=bi)

> וְזָרַקְתִּ֧י עֲלֵיכֶ֛ם מַ֥יִם טְהוֹרִ֖ים **וּטְהַרְתֶּ֑ם** מִכֹּ֧ל טֻמְאוֹתֵיכֶ֛ם וּמִכָּל־גִּלּ֥וּלֵיכֶ֖ם אֲטַהֵ֥ר אֶתְכֶֽם׃
>
> I will sprinkle clean water upon you, **and you shall be clean**: I will cleanse you from all your uncleanness and from all your fetishes.

**2)** [Leviticus 16:19](https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.16.19?lang=bi&aliyot=0)

> וְהִזָּ֨ה עָלָ֧יו מִן־הַדָּ֛ם בְּאֶצְבָּע֖וֹ שֶׁ֣בַע פְּעָמִ֑ים **וְטִהֲר֣וֹ** וְקִדְּשׁ֔וֹ מִטֻּמְאֹ֖ת בְּנֵ֥י יִשְׂרָאֵֽל׃
>
> and the rest of the blood he shall sprinkle on it with his finger seven times. Thus **he shall cleanse** it of the uncleanness of the Israelites and consecrate it.

**3)** [Leviticus 16:30](https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.16.30?lang=bi&aliyot=0)

> כִּֽי־בַיּ֥וֹם הַזֶּ֛ה יְכַפֵּ֥ר עֲלֵיכֶ֖ם **לְטַהֵ֣ר אֶתְכֶ֑ם** מִכֹּל֙ חַטֹּ֣אתֵיכֶ֔ם לִפְנֵ֥י יְהוָ֖ה תִּטְהָֽרוּ׃
>
> For on this day atonement shall be made for you to **cleanse you** of all your sins; you shall be clean before the LORD.